# Expression Engine - Breadcrumbs problem!

Tags: php, html, expressionengine

OK, I have set-up my breadcrumbs trial using IF segment and IF category_id statements. The reason being is because I have different products linking into 2-3 categories etc...

I have completed the whole trial and all works fine (alot of coding though!)

However, ONE category i'm having a big issue with, i've tried for hours to rectify it but can't, basically this category is in 2 parents and 2 children categories, under the one category group... All of the others have only one parent and one child so my code works fine.

I've tried everything, but it is bringing up

> > Toys >> Ben 10 >> Children >> Ben 10

It's repeating both categories and parents because the entry is in both of these in the one group... So I tried creating two seperate if statements away from my main if statement, like this:

My code is:

```
{if segment_2 == "view"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="toys"}
    {categories}
    {if parent_id == "25"}
    {if category_id == "31"}
    <li>
    <a href="(URL TO CATEGORY)">Toys</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="{path='toys/list'}">{category_name}</a>
    </li>
    {/if}
    {/if}
    {/categories}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}

{if segment_2 == "view"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="toys"}
    {categories}
    {if parent_id == "26"}
    {if category_id == "40"}
    <li>
    <a href="(URL TO CATEGORY)">Children</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="{path='toys/list'}">{category_name}</a>
    </li>
    {/if}
    {/if}
    {/categories}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

I would have assummed that defining the specific parent and cat id that this would display only one...

Any solutions?

Comment: I'd recommend getting into a habit of indenting your code -- this will help others understand and read your logic, while ensuring any nested tags are properly closed.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, it's often helpful to understand and "visualize" what the structure of the data you're dealing with is.

To get a sense of the [categories](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/categories.html) you're trying to wrangle for your breadcrumbs trail, use the following code to output each categories' `parent_id` and `category_id`:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="toys"}
    {categories}
        <strong>{category_name}</strong> [{parent_id}, {category_id}]<br />
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This will give you an output like:

```
Toys [0, 1]       // Parent Category
Children [1, 2]   // Child Category
```

Armed with this information, you can rework your conditional breadcrumbs to *deal with products classified in two or more categories*:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="toys"}
    {categories limit="2"}    
        {if parent_id == "0"}
            <!-- Show the Parent Category -->
            <li><a href="{path=toys/list}">{category_name}</a></li>
        {/if}

        {if parent_id != "0"}
            <!-- Show the Child Category -->
            <li><a href="{path=toys/list}">{category_name}</a></li>
        {/if}
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but it still doesn't work. It is now outputting the child category first and is still only displaying the same parent category in the ben 10 page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have an AND statement in your conditionals?
Something like
`{if parent_id == "26" && category_id == "40"}`

Just a guess. That means you're doing one check, and both conditions have to be true.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I tried that, it still shows both parents and both id's as I have 2 if conditionals and the entry is in each parent and each id...

Comment: Basically EE is taking the first IF statement and going - Yes it is in that parent id and yes it is in that category id. Then outputting the results. Then it's moving the the next IF statement and going, yes it is in that parent id too and yes it is in that category id... so it's outputting that also. I need it to just output one dependant on whether the user came from the category d_ben10 or c_ben10 (both of my category id names)